# Mounting a disk image

Tags: mount, freebsd

I created a backup from my laptop using the following command:

```
# dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 - | ssh backup-server "dd of=kubuntu-disk.gz"
```

On the backup server (FreeBSD 14.0-RELEASE-p4) I extracted the zipped disk to `kubuntu-disk.img` and now I want to mount the partitions to verify that I have a valid backup of my data. However, I am unable to mount the partitions.

```
# mdconfig -f kubuntu-disk.img
# gpart show /dev/md0
=>       34  500118125  md0  GPT  (238G)
         34       2014       - free -  (1.0M)
       2048    1083392    1  ms-recovery  (529M)
    1085440     204800    2  efi  (100M)
    1290240      32768    3  ms-reserved  (16M)
    1323008  270336000    4  ms-basic-data  (129G)
  271659008   81932288    6  linux-data  (39G)
  353591296  146526208    5  linux-data  (70G)
  500117504        655       - free -  (328K)
# fstyp /dev/md0p4
ntfs
# fstyp /dev/md0p5
ext2fs
# mount -t ntfs /dev/md0p4 /mnt
mount: /dev/md0p4: Invalid fstype: Invalid argument
# mount -t ext2fs /dev/md0p5 /mnt
mount: /dev/md0p5: Invalid argument
```

What am I doing wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you mount read only? Was Windows fast startup/hibernation on when you made the image? https://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/unable-to-mount-windows-10-partition-it-is-in-an-unsafe-state & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation & https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation

Comment: Providing the option `-o ro` does not change the output. Windows was shut down while making the backup of the disk. I am more interested in the ext4 partition (md0p5) then in the NTFS partition. I will read those linked articles. Thanks.

Comment: Cannot help as not familiar with dd & mounting images. I prefer not backing up system, only backing up /home & or data, list of installed apps and some settings in /. Years ago I lost a floppy drive thru damage to one sector that allowed read. Data was still there but compressed, but back then did not know how to recover it. So I want only files and multiple copies. Better to use rsync, not dd
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331348/can-i-use-dd-to-back-up-a-mounted-partition & https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Rsync#Full_system_backup

Comment: `/dev/sda` was not mounted, right? If the FS is dirty, do `fsck -t ext2fs /dev/md0p5`. Have you installed the proper tools to mount NTFS? There is also an `Invalid fstype` error message. If I recall correctly, the FreeBSD operating system ships ext2/3/4 mount and read/write support, but I would not be so sure about NTFS.